# How do I use Twitter Streaming API to track new followers of other accounts I don't have login information for?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm heavily basing my code off of this excellent [tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2010/04/tutorial-use-twitters-new-real-time-stream-api-in-python.ars) at Ars Technica, so I am able to track my own new followers because my login information is hard-coded in. However, I'd like to track new followers of other people's accounts too. How can I do this without their passwords?

```
import pycurl, json, StringIO
STREAM_URL = "http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?follow=[userid1],[userid2]&track=[keyword1],[keyword2]"
REST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/1/"

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.friends = []
        self.buffer = ""
        self.userid = None
        self.conn = pycurl.Curl()

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (username, password))
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, REST_URL + "account/verify_credentials.json")
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, output.write)
        self.conn.perform()

    data = json.loads(output.getvalue())
    if "error" in data: return False
    self.userid = data["id"]
    return True

    def connect(self):
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.on_receive)
        self.conn.perform()

    def on_receive(self, data):
        self.buffer += data
        if data.endswith("\r\n") and self.buffer.strip():
            content = json.loads(self.buffer)
            self.buffer = ""
            print content

        if "friends" in content:
            self.friends = content["friends"]

        elif "event" in content and content["event"] == "follow":  
            id_list = ['[userid1]','[userid2]']
            print "NEW FOLLOWER!!"
            print "target id:", content["target"]["id"]
            if content["target"]["id"] in id_list:  
                print content
                print "New follower:", content["source"]["name"], "(@" + content["source"]["screen_name"] + ")"  
            elif content["source"]["id"] == self.userid:  
                self.friends.append(content["target"]["id"])

        elif "text" in content:
            to = content["in_reply_to_user_id"]
            if to and to != self.userid and to not in self.friends: return
            if to == self.userid: print "(REPLY)",
            print u"{0[user][name]}: {0[text]}".format(content)

client = Client()  
if client.authenticate("[username]", "[password]"):  
    client.connect()  
else:  
    print "Login credentials aren't valid!"
```

Comment: FTFY -- if you indent code in the question window, it will be formatted as code (use backticks only for inline code).

Comment: Why can't you just add more `[userid]`s to your `follow` parameter and keep looking for follow events like you're currently doing? It doesn't seem that (as long as the users aren't protected) you need to be authenticated as a user to follow them with the stream api. If I'm on the right track, I'll expand this into an answer.

Comment: By follow parameter, do you mean the one in `STREAM_URL = "http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?follow=[userid1],[userid2]&track=[keyword1],[keyword2]"`? If so, adding userids to STREAM_URL only lets me track tweets by and about those users. That is exactly the problem that I was asking about in the original question. I should have clarified that my own userid isn't even included in the follow parameter, so tracking new followers must come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taylor Singletary](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=PMv52RwAAADziQ9bdKwaEHKLHT047zxKsEWQaXEousxizvRjwHNGlw) of Twitter responded to [the same question](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/f8c517a33f1d8da0) on the Google group for Twitter Development Talk:

> This is unfortunately not currently
>   possible with the Streaming API. 
>   Given the flexibility of followers/ids
>   and friends/ids API methods, tracking 
>   changes over time with those methods
>   would likely be your best avenue.

Comment: Bump, I guess. Is it now possible to get notifications of when a user gets a new follower?  The original poster suggested that he did not have the user's password; suppose that he DOES have the password, or has gotten the user to authorize himself with Twitter via OAuth, or perhaps through UserStreams?  (I'm pretty new to the streaming API and haven't completely digested this, so apologies if I'm doing/saying something stupid here...)  Thanks!