# Track new followers of a user using php and twitter streaming api

Tags: java, php, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I want to get notified when a particular user follows another user. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523364/how-do-i-use-twitter-streaming-api-to-track-new-followers-of-other-accounts-i-do) question but it was answered about 5yrs. back and things would have surely changed a lot.

Infact we can do this using java's twitter4j library. Checkout documentation [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/UserStreamListener.html#onFollow-twitter4j.User-twitter4j.User-)
The onFollow method gets invoked by the stream as soon as some user follows another. If this is possible using twitter4j, then it must be allowed by twitter streaming api for sure.

So how do I do this in php? (There is no blog neither any SO post about it)
Also I am unable to find the way to do this from twitter-api documentation.

Comment: Tried anything? Care to share?

Comment: @SamSwift웃 as the question says, java's twitter4j library allows doing the same. I have done this in java using twitter4j, but in php I could not find any library that provides the solution for the same. It seems that we have to write our own wrapper :(